# C++ USB communication

Tags: c++, windows, usb

I have a problem regarding communication with a **USB device** on Windows. I can't use libusb or WinUSB as I have a specific driver for that (Silabs USB to UART, which is a USB-to-serial bridge). This is how I initialize a device file, send&read data and close the handle.

```
HANDLE hDevFile = CreateFile(L"\\??\\USB#VID_10C4&PID_EA60#0001#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
PurgeComm(hDevFile, PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);

DCB dcbInitState;
GetCommState(hDevFile, &dcbInitState);

DCB dcbNewState = dcbInitState;
dcbNewState.BaudRate = 57600;
dcbNewState.Parity = NOPARITY;
dcbNewState.ByteSize = 8;
dcbNewState.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;

if (SetCommState(hDevFile, &dcbNewState) == 0)
{
    printf("Could not set COM state. Error: %i", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}

Sleep(60);

BYTE outData[8];
outData[0] = 0x53;
outData[1] = 0x10;
outData[2] = 0x04;
outData[3] = 0x10;
outData[4] = 0x40;
outData[5] = outData[3] ^ outData[4];
outData[6] = 0xAA;
outData[7] = 0x00;
DWORD dwWritten;

if (!WriteData(hDevFile, outData, 8, &dwWritten))
{
    printf("Could not write data. Error: %i", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}

BYTE inData[8];
DWORD dwRead;

if (!ReadData(hDevFile, inData, 8, &dwRead, 2000))
{
    printf("Could not read data. Error: %i", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}

SetCommState(hDevFile, &dcbInitState);
Sleep(60);
CloseHandle(hDevFile);
hDevFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
```

*(I get the device symbolic name from the registry but I've skipped that part to make my question concise. WriteData() and ReadData() are custom functions that write and read accordingly.)*

<strike>The problem is that SetCommState() returns a zero-value. GetLastError() returns 122, which is **ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER**.</strike>

The problem now is that PurgeComm() generates ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER, too. CreateFile() gives ERROR_SUCCESS, so it must be opened properly.

What's wrong? Did I miss something?

**Edit:** I tried enumerating COM ports and found an interesting thing - there are no COM ports on my computer. Even though the device is connected and enabled, with the driver present and all that stuff. I also tried forcefully putting \\.\COM1, \\.\COM2, and so on as the file name for CreateFile, but with no luck. Everytime got an ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Please, help. This is very important to me.

Comment: What platform please.

Comment: Have you checked the return value from GetCommState() to ensure that it's filling in the DCB structure that you go on to modify?

Comment: Well, apparently, GetCommState() returns ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER, too.

Comment: The DCB parameter to GetCommState() is documented as [in,out]. Zero it and set the DCBlength parameter to sizeof(DCB) before making the call.

Comment: PurgeComm() generates ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER too, so there isn't any problem with DCB.

Comment: @wassup Yes there is. You need to set  `dcb.DCBlength` before calling `GetCommState`, see e.g. the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363201(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Added that. No difference. PurgeComm() fails before even GetCommState() gets called.

Comment: The serial port winapi functions like Get/SetCommState() and PurgeComm() do *very* little, they have some minor argument validation, then directly pass the request to the driver with DeviceIoControl().  The driver is going to be very confused about that, those IOCTL codes are not valid for a USB device.  What error code it returns is fairly unpredictable.  You need to open the correct device.  Which is `"\\\\.\\COMx"` where `x` is the serial port number.  And yes, painful, not that easy to figure out what `x` might be if you have multiple ports.

Comment: How do I find out which port is one I'm looking for? I have information about USB port/hub (e.g. Port_#0001.Hub_#0003) from the registry. Is there any way to enumerate COM ports and check which one of them is port x and hub y?

Comment: I know that COM ports and USB ports are different things, but there must be a way to find out the USB-to-serial adapter port number.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a CP210x device, it's a virtual COM port, so you should be opening it as such in CreateFile. You had it right when you said that you tried using \.\COMx, you just need to find out which COM port your CP210x device has been assigned and you will not get the `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error. You can find this by looking in device manager:

[image]

Take a look a the [Serial Communications Guide for the CP210x](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/an197.pdf), this explains how to make these types of calls to your device, there's even a COM port discovery function that will help you find the COMxx name dynamically. It also has accompanying software, [AN197SW.zip](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/Software/AN197SW.zip).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Win32 Communication Functions just fine with a handle gotten from passing the device interface path to `CreateFile`.  I do this all the time.  Ignore the people telling you that you must use `COMx`.

However, it is important that you use the device interface path corresponding to the (virtual) serial port device (`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT`).  Many drivers are implemented as a pair of (USB device, serial port device), where the serial port is a child of the USB device.  Opening the USB device (`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE`) will not give you working communication functions, such as `PurgeCommState`.  (And this is exactly what you're trying now, note that the tail end of your device interface path exactly matches [the GUID documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545972.aspx))

If you don't have anything listed under the Ports section in Device Manager, you either don't have the driver correctly installed, or the device is not connected.

Once you get a port device found, you can use `CM_Get_Parent` to pair up the `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT` instance with the `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE`, solving your question of "What serial port is attached to USB in this particular way?"